# How can I display a success message after the user submit the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

```
        $('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
            resetErrors();
            $.each($('form input, form textarea, form select'), function(i, v){
                if(v.type !== 'submit'){
                    data[v.name] = v.value;
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'libs/contact.php',
                data: data,
                success: function(resp){
                    if(resp === true){
                        $('form').submit();
                        if(status == "success"){
                            console.log('Success')
                        }
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        $.each(resp, function(i, v){
                            console.log(i + " => " + v);
                            var msg = '<label class="error" for"' +i+ '">' +v+ '</label>';
                            $('input[name="' +i+ '"], textarea[name="' +i+ '"], select[name="' +i+ '"]').addClass('inputTextError').after(msg);
                        });
                        var keys = Object.keys(resp);
                        $('input[name="' +keys[0]+ '"]').focus
                    }
                    return false;
                },
                error: function(){
                    console.log('There was a problem checking fields');
                }

            });
            return false;
        });
    });
        function resetErrors(){
            $('form input, form textarea').removeClass('inputTextError');
            $('label.error').remove();
    }
```

Here's my code I have tried everything but still ain't working HELP PLZ
I'm doing all my validation on the server I'm just using ajax to display the errors so I would like to display the success message too but it's a little a bit confusing

Here's my PHP code

```
require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$errors = [];

if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['number'], $_POST['message'])){
    $fields = [
        'name' => $_POST['name'],
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'number' => $_POST['number'],
        'message' => $_POST['message']
    ];
    if(empty($fields['name'])){
        $errors['name'] = 'Come on you have a name right?';
    }
    if(empty($fields['email'])){
        $errors['email'] = 'Yes right, we need your email so that we contact you';
    }

    if(empty($fields['number'])){
        $errors['number'] = 'We also need your number';
    }

    if(empty($fields['message'])){
        $errors['message'] = 'You have come this far for sure you have something to say right';
    }
    if(count($errors) > 0){
        if ( !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest' ){
            echo json_encode($errors);
            exit;
        }

        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($errors as $key => $value){
            echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        exit;
    }
    /*foreach($fields as $field => $data){
        if(empty($data)){
            $errors[] = 'The ' . $field . ' field is required.';
        }
    }*/
    if(empty($errors)){
        $m = new PHPMailer;

        $m->isSMTP();
        $m->SMTPAuth = true;

        $m->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $m->Username = '';
        $m->Password = '';
        $m->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $m->Port = 465;

        $m->isHTML();

        $m->Subject = 'Contact form submitted';
        $m->Body = 'From: ' . $fields['name'] . '(' .$fields['email'] . ')<p>' . $fields['message'] . '</p><p>' . $fields['number'] . '</p>';

        $m->FromName = 'contact';

        $m->AddReplyTo($fields['email'], $fields['name']);

        $m->AddAddress('');

        if($m->send()){
            header('Location: ../contact.php');
            die();
        } else {
            $errors[] = 'Sorry could not send email. Try again later.';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'Oops something went wrong';
}

$_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
$_SESSION['fields'] = $fields;

header('Location: ../contact.php');
```

Comment: resp === true, this will never work, it has to be resp === 'true', since the data coming back from the server is a string, even if it's true or false.

Comment: Cool but that doesn't display a successfull message when the operatio was successful

Comment: if(status == "success"), where are you getting that status from ? Seems for me like you're checking on variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: Hmm okay now I thought success was supposed to check if the operation was a success

Comment: I also tried this but it's not working if(resp === 'true'){
       $('form').submit(function(){
        console.log('Success');
       });
       return false;

Comment: On your php side, are you ECHOING or PRINTING the string true out ? If you're using return on the php site, it won't help, since the ajax are taking all html echoed out on the php site it's calling. So you have to print or echo 'true'; on the php site.

Comment: I'm not returning anything that why I'm confused I add the my php code on the post you can check it

Comment: Can you add your php code above, then i'll show you how it should be done from the code you already have :)

Comment: I have upload my php

Comment: Okay. I've never used json when i've used ajax and php, but, what i'm always doing is that i'm posting to the php site, and then checking if resp == 'Success' and alerting success else alerting resp, i'm then echoing 'Success' where i'm expecting everything to be success in my php code, and else i'm echoing an error. Makes sense ?

Comment: Can you like code it and post it because I don't quiet understand the way you explaining it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to find out what is what in your code, but i guess this should work with the changes i've made.

jQuery / ajax

```
success: function(resp){
    if(resp === 'Success'){
        console.log('Success');
        $('form').submit();
        return false;
    } else {
        $.each(resp, function(i, v){
            console.log(i + " => " + v);
            var msg = '<label class="error" for"' +i+ '">' +v+ '</label>';
            $('input[name="' +i+ '"], textarea[name="' +i+ '"], select[name="' +i+ '"]').addClass('inputTextError').after(msg);
        });
        var keys = Object.keys(resp);
        $('input[name="' +keys[0]+ '"]').focus
    }
    return false;
}
```

PHP

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['number'], $_POST['message'])){
    $errors = array();
    $fields = [
        'name' => $_POST['name'],
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'number' => $_POST['number'],
        'message' => $_POST['message']
    ];
    if(empty($fields['name'])){
        $errors['name'] = 'Come on you have a name right?';
    }
    if(empty($fields['email'])){
        $errors['email'] = 'Yes right, we need your email so that we contact you';
    }

    if(empty($fields['number'])){
        $errors['number'] = 'We also need your number';
    }
    if(empty($fields['message'])){
        $errors['message'] = 'You have come this far for sure you have something to say right';
    }
    if(count($errors) > 0){
        if ( !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest' ){
            echo json_encode($errors);
            exit;
        }

        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($errors as $key => $value){
            echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        exit;
    }
    /*foreach($fields as $field => $data){
        if(empty($data)){
            $errors[] = 'The ' . $field . ' field is required.';
        }
    }*/
    if(empty($errors)){
        $m = new PHPMailer;

        $m->isSMTP();
        $m->SMTPAuth = true;

        $m->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $m->Username = '';
        $m->Password = '';
        $m->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $m->Port = 465;

        $m->isHTML();

        $m->Subject = 'Contact form submitted';
        $m->Body = 'From: ' . $fields['name'] . '(' .$fields['email'] . ')<p>' . $fields['message'] . '</p><p>' . $fields['number'] . '</p>';

        $m->FromName = 'contact';

        $m->AddReplyTo($fields['email'], $fields['name']);

        $m->AddAddress('hello@jilstudios.com', 'JIL Studios');

        if($m->send()){
            echo 'Success';
        } else {
            $errors[] = 'Sorry could not send email. Try again later.';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'Oops something went wrong';
}

$_SESSION['errors'] = $errors; $_SESSION['fields'] = $fields;

header('Location: ../contact.php');

?>
```